# Monero wallets with native xmr.to integration

Tags: xmr.to

Are there any Monero wallets with xmr.to native integration making it easy  to spend Monero at any Bitcoin accepting merchant?

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no wallets with native XMR.to integration. This is, however, planned for the official GUI at some point in the future.

**EDIT 12/25/2017:** Monerujo, a third-party Android wallet, currently has native XMR.to integration<sup>1</sup>

**Sources:**

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7lv9d8/update_monerujo_satoshis_dream_beta_now_with_btc/